# Using exec to relaunch crashing binary

Tags: bash, exec

Sorry, the question is pretty vague, but I hope someone still can help. 
As I understand `exec` bash command, it replaces the code segment with what is specified by an argument. Practically replace the running script with something else.

But I am pretty sure I saw people using `exec`(not `fork`) in a loop to relaunch executable if it crashes or just exits with non-zero exit code. Unfortunately I can't find that piece of code now. Is it at all possible or am I imagining things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know specifically what you saw, but there are conceivable ways of using exec in a loop to launch and relaunch a process, e.g.

```
while true
do
  ( unset DISPLAY && exec ./myfile )
done
```

The `( .. )` here is an explicit subshell, so there is a fork even if it's not obvious.

Other conceivable reasons for putting `exec` in a loop include trying to exec different files or different paths, until you find one that works or the file is created or becomes available.

However, there is no way to successfully `exec` a process without any kind of implicit or explicit fork, and then loop around to exec itself again (unless the script ends up execing itself in a recursive way).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about (...).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a more common problem than you'd think.

In the past, I've always implement a bash script to monitor if the process is there, and if it's not, restart it.

Here are some solutions that could work for you:
https://serverfault.com/questions/52976/simple-way-of-restarting-crashed-processes

Comment: Yeah, I am sure there are different ways to monitor the process, but I'm curious about the 'exec' usage for this(thank you for the link, though. It is helpful)